# загрузка страницы в asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Проблема с отловом событий на странице. Есть большой проект. Для каждой web  страницы есть aspx и aspx.cs с событиями страницы. Но стартовая выполнена иначе. Не могу понять как она заполняется. Вот что находится на стартовой странице.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            SessionVariables.SelectedAggregate = null;
            SessionVariables.SelectedUnit = null;
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

А вот код Home.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Но на странице есть дроп дауны и другие элементы. Не пойму откуда это всё заполняется. Наверно не до конца понимаю принципы asp.net. Если кто то может объяснить куда лезть что бы найти где всё это заполняется или что почитать что бы это всё понимать подскажите пожалуйста. Желательно оба варианта если можно.

Comment: "на странице есть дроп дауны и другие элементы" - посмотрите содержимое файла Home.aspx

Comment: @Igor там пусто, но уже разобрался где и что находиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стартовая страница на заполняется. Она всегда перенаправляет пользователя на Home.aspx.